# Using DEFINE and VERIFY commands in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am studying for oracle certified associate exam, and one of the objectives list using the DEFINE and VERIFY commands. I dont see anything in the docs, nor any useful information on the web. Can someone please help define these commands with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What docs are you looking at, that you say you cannot find anything?  The SQL*Plus User Guide and Reference has it all, including examples.

[DEFINE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/DEFINE.html#GUID-72D4998C-EC2C-4FA6-9F7F-A305C407D666)

VERIFY - this is not a command but a clause of the [SET command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SET.html#GUID-9095C4FF-F4EB-4218-84AA-83061186625F).

Comment: Thats strange, thats were i was looking.... here is the URL https://docs.oracle.com/apps/search/search.jsp?word=DEFINE&product=b28359-01&book=b28286

Comment: I see it now, for some reason or another I was using the older reference guide, it only went up 11g.

Comment: It's existed forever. e.g. [8i docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a82950/ch8.htm#1001850)

Comment: I'm not even sure what that link was. Obviously it was from docs.oracle.com, but looks like some aggregation of a search.  I have no idea what you did to get there.  I simply bookmark the book list for the version I'm interested in. Go to https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/index.html.  There will be  drop-list to select which version of oracle. The result of that will be a portal or complete book list (depending on version) of all the docs for the selected version.